# Iframe (WooCommerce) and login with Facebook in Ionic app

Tags: angular, wordpress, typescript, ionic-framework, woocommerce

I have an ionic app with an iframe from Wordpress website. In my home.page.ts I have this code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  public cleanSupportURL: any;
  sanitizer: DomSanitizer;
  url: string = "https://domain.com.ar";


  constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
      this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
      this.cleanSupportURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
      this.cleanSupportURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.fb);

  }
}
```

And my home.page.html:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-content>
      <iframe [class]="webPage" [name]="samplePage" scrolling="yes" [src]="cleanSupportURL">
      </iframe>
  </ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

Everything is doing fine except the login with Facebook and Google. When I try to log in with Facebook the screen shows me this:

> La página web de
>   https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=536079400554654&kid_directed_site=0&app_id=536079400554654&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fv3.2%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fresponse_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3D536079400554654%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fvinapp.com.ar%252Fwp-login.php%253FloginSocial%253Dfacebook%26state%3D6044938ac15b05b5ac06d1886069f1df%26scope%3Dpublic_profile%252Cemail%26ret%3Dlogin%26fbapp_pres%3D0%26logger_id%3D183a5111-c149-4a83-8a11-6263dbddab6c&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fvinapp.com.ar%2Fwp-login.php%3FloginSocial%3Dfacebook%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26state%3D6044938ac15b05b5ac06d1886069f1df%23_%3D_&display=touch&locale=es_LA&pl_dbl=0&refsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fvinapp.com.ar%2Flogin%2F&_rdr
>   no se pudo cargar porque:
>
> net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Any idea how to fix it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Wifi is restricting Facebook.

Just turn off Your **WIFI** and use **Mobile Data** then check it...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but, it isn't work... The problem is in the Facebook iframe permissions I think